# How do I generate the correct volume contour from a raster using sf, spatialEco, and terra?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, kernel-density, terra

I am interested in using R packages spatialEco and terra to generate some kernel density estimates with data of varying weights so that I can export contour shapefiles for mapping. I'm currently having trouble with generating a contour polygon from the data. `sf.kde` and `raster.vol` return `SpatRaster` objects, which I am attempting to convert to polygons via `as.contour` from terra. However, the resulting contours have 10 levels even though I specified the percentage I am interested in from `raster.vol`.

I'm not seeing any way to return a single layer from the `as.contour` function. Which of these levels in the `spatVector` returned by `as.contour` aligns with the percent threshold designated for the raster volume? Is there a different way to go about generating this contour?

Here is an example

```
# Generate 75% PVC from point data
library(sf)
library(spatialEco)
library(terra)

set.seed(500)

# Example Data
lims <- data.frame(x = c(0,10),
                   y = c(5,15))

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50,  4, 1.0),
                  y = rnorm(50, 11, 0.5))

# plot(dat, xlim = lims$x, ylim = lims$y)

# Convert data to sf coordinates
dat_sf <- st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("x","y"))
# plot(dat_sf)

# Generate kde using spatialEco
dat_kde <- sf.kde(dat_sf,
                  y = NULL,
                  bw = 2,
                  res = .5,
                  ref = c(lims$x, lims$y))
# plot(dat_kde)

# Generate Percent Volume Raster from KDE
dat_vol <- raster.vol(dat_kde,
                      p = .75)

plot(dat_vol, xlim = c(2,6), ylim = c(9,13))
contour(dat_vol, add = T)

# Get Percent Volume Contour from Raster
dat_con <- as.contour(dat_vol)
```

[Here are the resulting contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElKdy.png)

Comment: I can't provide a full answer since I am not familiar with `spatialEco`, but you can fine-tune the output of `as.contour()` passing parameters `level` or `nlevels`. This is documented under `...` since `as.contour` relies in `graphics::contour()`, see in the terra docs under `...` and follow the link https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/contour.html